# How to I avoid storing a local copy of predecessor versions with subversion?

Tags: svn

I use subversion for all my code even on the local machine. Since the repository is always available on my machine, there is really no need for .svn subdirectories which store a copy of the predecessor.  Is there a way I can avoid this and let the subversion always talk to the repository for the predecessor whenever there is a need?  I understand it may be a performance hit, but it is ok. I am running out of disk space some times.

There are several working copies using this repository and, by policy, all those working copies use the same predecessor revision. We need to conserve some disk space on this machine by avoiding (if possible) .svn directories of this huge code base in each working-copy.

Answer (score 1):

An indirect answer...  We used to have the same problem with `svn`, but then we switched to `git`.  IIRC, we saved several times on disk space and increased speed by about 10X.

Since git is a distributed SCM, it is perfect for storing local-only copies of files and folders.  In fact, our entire administrative file share is versioned in git for historical integrity and research purposes.

Consider the switch, you won't look back...

Comment: IIRC when I write out what I mean to say instead of abbreviating it I get better at varying my language.

Comment: However, each copy of the repository has the entire history.  So if he has multiple checked out copies (using SVN terminology) he still has multiple copies.  You're just reducing the number of copies by one using Git.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to avoid .svn directories. As far as I know, even when you use ra-local (local repository access) they are created.

If you are using a local server anyway why wouldn't you consider using one of the distributed revision control systems instead of Subversion (Git, Mercurial, Bazaar). They all are very conscious about space and are very good at compressing the repository down to the minimum size.

Comment: AFAIK abbreviations are monotonous and uncreative.

Comment: IIRC AFAIK is an acr. not an abbr., FYI JSYK.

Comment: An acronym is an abbreviation:   
Acronym  -  An acronym is a word formed from the first (or first few) letters of a series of words that is used as an abbreviation to refer to that series of words. A few examples of acronyms are NYSE is the acronym for the New York Stock Exchange, DRIP is the acronym for Dividend ReInvestment Program, and QUIPS is the acronym for QUarterly Interest Preferred Securities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to wait for svn 1.7, and even then I'm not sure if it will fully satisfy your requirements, but there are [working copy improvements](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/wc-improvements) based on a [new design](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/wc-ng-design). Also see [this issue](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3357).

Maybe someone on the development team will answer this question, if not, you're probably better off asking the Subversion mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of the `.svn` directories because they are what make your working copy a working copy.  Without them, you don't have an SVN working copy anymore.